# SQL Query (Simple)

Tags: group-by, sql

I would like to know how could a return the number of songs registred each year based on this table:

```
Musics={MusicID, SingerID, Recorder, YearOfRecord}
MusicID as PK
```

Thanks for the attention

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the correct query would be:

```
SELECT YearOfRecord, Count(MusicID) as NumberOfSongs
FROM Musics
GROUP BY YearOfRecord
ORDER BY YearOfRecord
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT Count(MusicID)
FROM Musics
GROUP BY YearOfRecord
```

That query should work

Comment: For each year, it will create a new column on the answer?
Thanks

Comment: It will create a new row, not column :). And yes, for each different year it will create a new entry on the result.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(*) AS NumberOfSongs,
    YearOfRecord
FROM
    Musics
GROUP BY
    YearOfRecord
ORDER BY
    YearOfRecord
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select YearOfRecord, COUNT(MusicID) AS NumberOFSongs
   FROM Musics GROUP BY YearOfRecord
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select count(*), YearOfRecord 
from Musics
group by YearOfRecord
```